# Chaining an installer for an exe and msi

Tags: wix, windows-installer, exe, chain

I have written a plugin for an application which has an installer as an executable. My plugin is installed using an msi, written in wix. We've now been given permission to distribute the two together. Ideally, this would be in a single file with two installations. Both parts would need to be updated seperately, particularly the main program, I have read that this restricts the methods of installation.

I'm having trouble installing the main program first, then the plugin. I have tried including this main exe in the wix as a custom action, but I'm worried that this will mess things up when either program needs updating. I have seen something called an MsiEmbeddedChainer but can't seem to find anywhere that describes how to implement it.

Any advice, or pointers of useful articles would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you need to know is linked from the [Not supported in Windows Installer 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736323%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) document, but it will likely still take a lot of trial and error. [This blog post](http://softwareinstall.blogspot.com/2008/06/fun-with-msiembeddedchainer.html) has a lot of interesting points to help with rough patches along the way. However let me warn you that my experience with InstallShield has shown that MsiEmbeddedChainer chaining is not as reliable as bootstrap chaining, at least in environments with Terminal Services.